# How to show custom window over map like Google Maps' POI window?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a window upon marker click in my app like in this [Sample image](http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/jLJeyIQjVnq4pvWJMNVjnr1-EEI=/fit-in/850x850/http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2Fwp-content%2Fgallery%2Fsaving-google-maps-locations-offline%2FIMG_8189.PNG). I know about the `InfoWindowAdapter` and how you can customize the two methods to get your desired details on marker, but I need additional details like images and videos and I want them to be viewed in fullscreen or played respectively. How can I go about to get this type of layout?

Comment: Take a look at [bottom sheets](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html)

Comment: @antonio thanks, I think this may do the trick. Any tutorials you may know?

Comment: @ateebahmed take a look at this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)

Comment: @TranHieu thanks, I used the same article and created a bottom sheet fragment and set it on marker click listener but whenever I press a marker, screen dims but the bottom sheet does not appear like in the article mentioned

Comment: my mistake! I wasn't setting any UI elements placed in the layout